# Issue Building Angular Module Package with Angular 5 Compiler

Tags: angular, npm

I am having an issue using an Angular Module Package after upgrading to using Angular 5.  I have determined that the issue is with the Angular CLI Compiler (NGC).  I am expecting the following output from the compiler in the compiled javascript:

```
LibService.ctorParameters = () => [];

class LibModule {
}
LibModule.decorators = [
    { type: NgModule, args: [{
                declarations: [LibComponent],
                providers: [LibService],
                exports: [LibComponent]
            },] },
];
/**
 * @nocollapse
 */
LibModule.ctorParameters = () => [];
```

Instead, what I am getting as a result is:

```
class LibModule {
}
```

Which obviously doesn't have any of the decorators or annotations that describe the module.  The same is true for the services and components included.

My tsconfig.json looks like the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

and my tsconfig.lib.json is:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib-es2015/",
    "target": "es2015",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "./index.ts",
    "./typings.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "flatModuleOutFile": "quickstart-lib.js",
    "flatModuleId": "quickstart-lib",
    "genDir": "../../out-tsc/lib-gen-dir/"
  }
}
```

The line I am using in my javascript to build under the 4.0 compiler is:

```
ngc({ project: `${tempLibFolder}/tsconfig.lib.json` })
```

and for the 5.0 compiler it is:

```
ngc(['-p', `${tempLibFolder}/tsconfig.lib.json` ])
```

I have not been able to find any good documentation about the other options for `angularCompilerOptions` that would provide any guidance.

When I compile I do get this warning that I have not been able to find useful information on to solve this issue:

```
'Component', 'Injectable' and 'NgModule' are imported from external module '@angular/core' but never used
```

Comment: You might be interested in how angular material checks it https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/tools/package-tools/build-bundles.ts#L106-L111